# Calculating a safe maximum size for a List

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to calculate the maximum safe size for a list before needing to create a new one. I am thinking about using the size of the data structure, based off of the type, and dividing 1 GB (since 2 GB is the < .Net 4.5 limit) by it to see how many elements I can possibly stick in a list safely. Perhaps maxnumber - 3, in case of overhead and what not.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you need a database....

Comment: What would your List contain ?

Comment: And what platfhorm (x86 or x64) you are targeting? 2GB is mostly theoretical limit for x86... BTW, why 1GB/sizeof(item)?

Comment: I think the limit of a List<T> is Int32.Max, regardless of the size of the elements. The the maximum heap size will limit the amount of elements you will be able to add and that depends no the size of each data structure in the list.

Comment: Frankly, at that scale I'd be working with jagged fragments stitched together by some encapsulating class. The maximum fragment size does not need to be the biggest possible - you could arbitrarily choose 2^20, for example

Comment: 64-bit, for an evolutionary program.

Comment: It's 1 GB / sizeof(item), as the trying to double the list to 2 GBs seems to throw an out of memory exception. I am implementing a list of lists, so I need to know how large I should let one of them grow before creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get list of items that is backed by byte array of almost 2Gb (if you try to grow the list dynamically it will obviously fail close to half of max size due to reallocation stategy).

If you data is not immutable you may instead consider GC friendlier approach that does not create many objects on LOH. Try targeting all allocations to be under limit of LOH allocation (I think 85Kb) and measure if code behaves better.

Answer (score 1):

If your list contains structures, your approach would work, but you'll need to take memory alignment into account (it can cause an error of much more than 3...). If it's a reference type, your element size is 4 (on a 32-bit CLR) or 8 (on a 64-bit CLR).

However, if this is even a problem for you, you should consider using an alternative. Either store the entire list elsewhere (a database?) and bring the parts you need to memory, or use a different data structure, such as a list of lists (basically fragmenting your data), placing 100,000 elements in each small list.

Comment: I am indeed attempting a list of lists. However, I can only stick about 1 GB of data into an individual list before .Net starts complaining. So, I intend to calculate the maximum safe size for a list before creating a new one, and appending it to the list of lists.

Comment: Why not store 100MB of data in each individual list, and not worry about it?

Comment: Because that creates a great many lists, such that for every extra depth of lists, it increases the number of instructions to access it by one. If you have a few billion elements, and are trying to calculate a few million operations per second, it all adds up.

Comment: @user978122, how much memory you machine have???? 180000 (180K) element arrays will address 32GB of bytes with one indirection...

Comment: 16 GBs on the laptop, 32 GBs on my main machine, and I am contemplating a server with 256-512 GBs, depending on how this prototype works out.

Comment: It creates 10 times the number of 1GB list. I don't think this will add up to much, 100MB is way way more than can be added to any reasonable CPU cache (which will be responsible for the real performance you'll see when traversing those lists). Since you already want to handle lists of different sizes, just try with 100MB, then with 500MB and see if you witness any reasonable performance increase.